# email sending by android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND do not display email picker:

Tags: android

I notice if I use the below code to sedn email, email compse is shown. however, I can't pick email from contact, rather I have to fill up email address. Is there aay to let user pick up an email address from contact:

```
 public void sendSimpleEmail(View button) {
        try {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            startActivity(emailIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "sendSimpleEmail() failed to start activity.", e);
            Toast.makeText(this, "No handler", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It really depends on the email application, some may allow some may not

Comment: does "email application" depends on handset manufacture like Samsung, Sony Ericsson, Motorola .... etc ... or it depends on what?

Comment: yeah, it depends on the manufacturer. Sometimes even same manufacturer have different email apps on different phones

Comment: Oh .. i see .. I tried this on simulator only... Thank you for your explanation!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "nandeesh" answered above, it depends on the email application, some may allow some may not . In my case i was trying with simulator only.

Answer (score 1):

replace your `startActivity(emailIntent);` with `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent));`